# Intellij new project - JDK not available

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, project, java-6

Hopefully this is an simple question with a simple answer -

I am using Intellij as my IDE and want to create a new Java project. When I go to create a new project, I get an error saying `<No SDK>` and `download JDK` with a link to download the JDK. I have the JDK downloaded already. How am I able to get Intellij to see the install? I assume I am missing a step to connect the two.

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to click on New.. and locate your JDK on your computer.
Which is most likely to be in C:/Program Files/Java/jdk

Comment: thank you. I tried that earlier but I got "the selected directory is not a valid home for JDK". Do you know if it is inside of one of the folders? I've tried pretty much all of them except for the obvious ones like legal.

Comment: @Olivia You should be choosing the parent folder that contains bin,conf,legal.. etc.. in your case, it should be jdk-10.0.1. have you tried that?

Comment: Do you get the same message for all JDK installations? There might be some issues with JDK 10

Comment: @Decarbon I have tried that. I get the same error no matter what folder (the main jdk-10.0.1 or it's subfolders) I try to select

Comment: @y.bedrov yes, it does not appear to be picking up any JDK installations. Do you think I should try to install jdk 8 agian?